# ModernCV and removing blank lines on header

Tags: moderncv

I have disabled the address (`%\address{}{}{}`), but I cannot remove the blank rows above my Phone number/email address/social media. Can we put the phone number/email/social on the top beside the photo? I'm quite new with LaTeX and would need some help.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 


\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{orange}   

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{eurosym}
%\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage[scale=0.90, top=0.5cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry} %If you want to change the page margins, you simply need to change this line

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.5cm} 

\name{David}{Doe}
%\title{Audit, Risk and Compliance\newline{}PMP®, ITIL, CRISC} 
\title{PMP®, ITIL, CRISC} 
%\address{}{}{}
\phone[mobile]{+XXXXXXXX} 
\email{emil.com}  
\social[linkedin][WWWWW]{ZZZZ}
\photo[80pt][0pt]{David_linkedn}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you gave no complete MWE I used simply an example of an CV included with `moderncv` class.

The following is simply a bad and dirty hack (because it is not easy to change the complex code producing the title of the CV): I use simply `\extrainfo{...}` you did not use in the given code snippet and add there as many lines as needed writen in white textcolor like:

```
\extrainfo{\textcolor{white}{additional information} \\ % <=============
  \textcolor{white}{additional information} \\ % <======================
  \textcolor{white}{additional information} \\
  \textcolor{white}{additional information} \\
  \textcolor{white}{additional information }} % <=======================
```

That depends on the image you are using. I needed five lines because I used example image `example-image-golden-upright` from package `mwe` (must be installed but not called!). Just play with the number of used lines in your case ...

With the following complete TeX  code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic} % head 1, body 1, foot -
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[%
  scale=0.75,
  top=0.5cm, bottom=1cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.5cm} 



\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
%\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
%\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
%\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
%\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
%\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{\textcolor{white}{additional information} \\ % <=============
  \textcolor{white}{additional information} \\ % <======================
  \textcolor{white}{additional information} \\
  \textcolor{white}{additional information} \\
  \textcolor{white}{additional information }} % <=======================
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-golden-upright}%
\quote{Some quote}

\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother
%\renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description 
  no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description 
  line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{\textbf{Language} 2}{\textbf{Skill} level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore 
  normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation 
  when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}

\end{document}
```

I get the following resulting pdf (as wished):

[image: resulting CV]

As you can see (long red arrow) the additional information is there (needs the marked place), but it is not visible, because it is printed in white color ...